# How to select by expression multiple rows in attribute table

Tags: qgis, select-by-expression

I have a large number of parcels to select, which id number are in Field Name "numberofparcel". How can I make an expression with group of parcels to select by their id number? I use QGIS 2.18

Comment: Please tell us, which software you're working with, by editing your question and adding the corresponding tag.

Comment: Select or filter? For filter use standart SQL statements like "numberofparcel" in (1, 2, 3 ...) or "numberofparcel" > 123

Comment: i want to select for example parcels with id number 1004, 1385, 1450 etc

Comment: Then open attribute table, press "select by expression" button and write expression: "numberofparcel" in (1004, 1385, 1450)